# Spark Streaming throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark Streaming in cluster mode is throwing `FileNotFoundException` with linux file system (GFS - shared file system across all nodes) but working fine with HDFS as input.

Data is actually available and accessible on this path from all the worker nodes.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> myDStream =
    jssc.fileStream(path, Text.class, Text.class, customInputFormat.class, new Function<Path, Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean call(Path v1) throws Exception {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
      }
    }, false);
```

error message:

```
14/06/03 21:33:40 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /data/spark/input does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:697)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$600(DistributedFileSystem.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$15.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$15.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1485)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1525)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.findNewFiles(FileInputDStream.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream.compute(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream.compute(FlatMappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:241)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(JobGenerator.scala:86)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
14/06/03 21:33:40 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1433347420000 ms:
```

**Note:**
Spark shell works with this shared file system.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> myDStream =
    jssc.fileStream(path, Text.class, Text.class, customInputFormat.class, new Function<Path, Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean call(Path v1) throws Exception {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
      }
    }, false);
```

resolved after directory path is prefixed with `file:///`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that probably it's **permission** problem.

Make sure, when you run the job, you are under the user with sufficient privilege (for master node or the machine you submit the job ) to ssh to worker nodes and r/w/x on worker file system.

Comment: all the nodes have r/w/x access to the path.